# IE on windows 8 Can I remove selected tabs from the restore last session list before the restore

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

I have windows 8 installed on my system with IE 11.0.9600.
I have about 30 some tabs open while searching for some information. I opened one more and IE hung. When I try to restore last session It brings up all the tabs but it seems to be jumping from one tab to another and is very slow. Mouse movement takes about 7 minutes.

A number of tabs are related to an information search I am doing. These I want to analyze further. There are many others open that are not that important.
Is there a file that can be edited before "restore last session" to remove some of the tabs that are expendable. I am guessing that IE would then be able to restore the rest without problems.

Hope this is enough info to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: There is a file, which handles which tabs are restored, but there isn't any published information on the contents of the file itself.  There are tools that have reversed engineered the contents, but they do not do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop version of IE has a History list (click the star icon, top-right, then choose the History tab) which you might be able to use to get back to the pages you wanted.

It seems to be shared by IE Modern (or whatever the tablet version is called now).